# Datatables mysql charset circumflex

Tags: php, mysql, datatable, character-encoding

I have a mysql database with latin1 default character set name.
Through php I save strings in mysql table. From the table I parse some data into tables using DataTables.
Everything work ok, but now I have some problems with circumflex letters and FPDF.

So if I save a string "račun" in the table, the result in the table will be "raÄun".
Or the string "število" will be "Å¡tevilo".

OK -> DataTables decodes those words back normally..
But now when I am using FPDF it gets those string as they are stored in MySQL table and print them "encoded".

I tried

```
iconv("ISO-8859-1", "ISO-8859-2", "Števika računa")
```

and

```
utf8_decode("Števika računa)
```

But nothing worked.. does anybody has an idea what should I do?

Comment: Check the encoding of your php file. I had that issue and it took me days to realize that the php file had a wrong charset. AND why don't you use utf8_general_ci? I mean, you can't use utf8_decode with a latin1 string

Comment: I thought I set it up, but it was set only for the tables?...anyway now I set it to utf8_general_ci for the whole database... I deleted all the data from the table and inserted a new record.. the data is saved as before and in FPDF I get the char ? if I use utf8_decode...

Comment: i'm sorry that i couldn't help you. Make sure that every script that reads the data keeps it in utf8. isn't there any option in FPDF to set a charset for the created document? i used pdflib and there i was able to choose a charset. and chwck the charset with thisfunction: mb_check_encoding($string, 'UTF-8'); you can check for all charsets you want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end this was the solution:

http://isabelcastillo.com/international-characters-encoding-fpdf